# Write into the CSV

Tags: c#, csv

at first I am a novice, I am learning is that only two months. (Sorry for my english, I hope u will understand.)
Problem is:
I am trying to create a small database with console application. I have student.csv where are all information about students. When I start application, all informations from this .csv will save into Lists. Like this:

```
    List<Student> zoznam = new List<Student>();
    List<string> inicZac = new List<string>();
    List<string> ID = new List<string>();
    List<string> Meno = new List<string>();
    List<string> Priezvisko = new List<string>();
    List<string> Adresa = new List<string>();
    List<string> DatumNarodenia = new List<string>();
    List<string> Heslo = new List<string>();
    List<string> Login = new List<string>();
    List<string> inicKon = new List<string>();
    private int id;

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("student.csv"));  

    public databazaStudentov()
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            inicZac.Add(values[0]);
            ID.Add(values[1]);
            Meno.Add(values[2]);
            Priezvisko.Add(values[3]);
            Adresa.Add(values[4]);
            DatumNarodenia.Add(values[5]);
            Heslo.Add(values[6]);
            Login.Add(values[7]);
            inicKon.Add(values[8]);
            zoznam.Add(new Student(values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7]));
        }

    }
```

It works good. But now I want secure an easy write into this .csv when I create a new student in a running application.This function is creating a new student:

```
    public void addStudent(string meno, string priezvisko, string adresa, string datum)
    {
        string tempID = generujID(); //random gener ID
        string tempLogin = generujLogin(meno, priezvisko); //random gener Login
        string tempHeslo = generujHeslo(); //random gener password
        zoznam.Add(new Student(tempID, meno, priezvisko, adresa, datum, tempLogin, tempHeslo));
        ID.Add(tempID);
        Meno.Add(meno);
        Priezvisko.Add(priezvisko);
        Adresa.Add(adresa);
        DatumNarodenia.Add(datum);
        Login.Add(tempLogin);
        Heslo.Add(tempHeslo);
        // I created a new student and now I want save him into the csv
    }
```

and here is my .csv: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyGCy.jpg

There are probably more ways how to fix it. I will be gratefull if someone show me How to save a new student on a new row or How to overwrite with Lists everything in my student.csv . Thanks for tips and sorry for my english.

Comment: `string.Join` is the counterpart to `string.Split`

Comment: just curious why csv as storage format?  I'd go with something like JSON that can easily be serialized and deserialized into C# object and has better support for hierarchical data structure just in case.  And since you are using file system anyhow, you can just persist and read it as a whole.  Flow is something like: load json from storage, deserialize into C# object, make changes in C# object like remove from list or add to list, etc., serialize back to json and write to storage.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new class to create csv file from your student.

```
public class CsvGen
{
  private _fileName=string.Empty;
  private StringBuilder csvRows;
  public CsvGen(string fileName)
  {
    _fileName=fileName;
    csvRows=new StringBuilder();
  }

  public void Add(Student student)
  {
    var row=String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}",student.Id,student.Name,student.City,
                                                                 Environment.NewLine);
    csvRows.Append(row);
  }
  public void SaveFile()
  {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(_fileName,csvRows.ToString());
  }
}
```

Now from your other class, you can create a new instance of this class and call the AddStudent method everytime you add an item to the list and call SaveFile after your loop.

```
CsvGen csvGen=new CsvGen(@"C:\\temp\myFile.csv"); 
// ^ any location with proper permission for .net to write files.

public void AddStudent(int id, string name, string city)
{
   Student stud=new Student();
   stud.Id=id;
   stud.Name=name;
   stud.City=city;
   csvGen.Add(stud);     
}
```

So once you create all students, You may call the `SaveFile` method to save the csv file

```
while (!someCondition) 
{
  AddStudent(2,"scott","detroit");
}
csvGen.SaveFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution for your question.

```
public void addStudent(string meno, string priezvisko, string adresa, string datum)
{
    //your code 
    //.........

    // I created a new student and now I want save him into the csv
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("student.csv", true))//true to append after the file
    {
        sw.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};",
            tempID, meno, priezvisko, adresa, datum, tempLogin, tempHeslo);  
        sw.Close();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and write csv, then I'd recommend you try the [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) library, as it would be much simpler than the way you're doing it currently.